# Headers fragment item listener

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to print out in console headers fragment item titles/id's on dpad movement using listener. What am I doing wrong and is there maybe an alternative to accomplish my goal?

For instance:

[image]

Would print out "Category 3" or "...." id.

```
public class XFragment extends BrowseFragment {

  //onCreate()

     setOnItemViewSelectedListener(new OnItemViewSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, 
        Object item, RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Here!");
        }      
    });       
}
```

I can't even "catch" the selection between header items.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself. Turns out, it was quite easy.

```
if (getHeadersFragment() != null){
        getHeadersFragment().setOnHeaderViewSelectedListener(new HeadersFragment.OnHeaderViewSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHeaderSelected(RowHeaderPresenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Row row) {
                // catch your item by row.getId();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Use setOnHeaderViewSelectedListener() will break BrowseSupportFragment. So, let use getHeadersSupportFragment().getSelectedPosition(); => header item title.